# How to set language when generating pdf in Laravel

Tags: laravel, dompdf, laravel-5.8

Is there a way to force the language when generating a pdf in laravel?

I'm using the package `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` and creating the pdf with a blade view like so:

```
 $pdf = PDF::loadView('businesssummary::report.pdf', [
            "vm" => $result,
            'locale' => Cache::get('locale', 'default')
        ]);
```

When streaming the pdf directly into a page, like so

```
'<div class="container"><embed src="{{ Loc::route('directory.report') }}" width="100%" height="1120" type="application/pdf" scrolling="yes"></embed></div>'
```

it works great and uses the current locale.

But when creating the pdf to be used as an attachement in an email sent to the user, the language used is the app default one.

Can I set the locale for this, just like I do so for the email sent?
I can't seem to find documentation on how (or if possible) to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out a simple way to do it.

Just before loading the view with `PDF::loadView(...)`, just set the locale using the value stored in the Cache like so:

`App::setLocale(Cache::get('locale', 'default'));`